# How to check for item in documentElement, 'in' is not working

Tags: coffeescript

In JavaScript I have this test `'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement`. If the event exists (even if null) it evaluates to `true` otherwise to `false`. I don't know how to do the equivalent in CoffeeScript. Writing it exactly as is translates to using an `__indexOf` function which does not do the same thing (it is always returning false).

*You can also try `'onmousemove'` for an event that always exists.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `of` instead :

```
'ontouchstart' of document.documentElement
```

From [the documentation](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) :

> You can use `in` to test for array presence, and `of` to test for
>   JavaScript object-key presence.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work, but why? Isn't `of` the map comprehension operator?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y I added an extract from the documentation